# Successful yeoman generator install can't be found when running yo?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, terminal, mean-stack

Currently failing to learn how to use terminal as a development tool.

Trying to set up the MEAN stack by using yeoman to scaffold the project. However, when I run `npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack` it installs successfully here (/Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules) and then when I run `yo angular-fullstack` it says I haven't got that generator.

I have two generators installed already but the new generator (angular-fullstack) isn't adding to the list even though the global install was successful:

```
mean
meanjs
```

This might be irrelevant but when I try and uninstall these generators I get this message - `npm WARN uninstall not installed in /Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules`

What I'm trying to do is:

```
1. install the angular-fullstack generator
2. scaffold a project using angular-fullstack
```

I've tried uninstalling yeoman, npm, clearing npm cache and all sorts of things but I can't get it to work. I've been working on this on and off for about 3 weeks now and all I want to do is get a mean project structure set up and running. So if anyone can help that'd be great.

Being a rookie I didn't want to resort to Stack Overflow, but I'll take the abuse now. ;)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Tried to install a different generator (angular) and can't access this either. This is the message I get when installing.

```
~:TestMVCApp xxxx$ npm install -g generator-angular
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency generator-karma@>=0.9.0 included from generator-angular will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency yo@>=1.0.0 included from generator-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
generator-karma@1.0.0 /Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-karma
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── underscore@1.8.3
└── yeoman-generator@0.19.2 (detect-conflict@1.0.0, read-chunk@1.0.1, diff@1.4.0, yeoman-welcome@1.0.1, xdg-basedir@1.0.1, user-home@1.1.1, rimraf@2.4.3, async@0.9.2, mime@1.3.4, text-table@0.2.0, class-extend@0.1.2, dargs@4.0.1, shelljs@0.4.0, debug@2.2.0, nopt@3.0.4, istextorbinary@1.0.2, cross-spawn@0.2.9, mkdirp@0.5.1, chalk@1.1.1, yeoman-assert@1.0.0, cli-table@0.3.1, run-async@0.1.0, mem-fs-editor@1.2.3, through2@0.6.5, underscore.string@3.2.2, glob@5.0.15, findup-sync@0.2.1, yeoman-environment@1.2.7, sinon@1.17.1, github-username@1.1.1, dateformat@1.0.11, pretty-bytes@1.0.4, gruntfile-editor@1.0.0, lodash@3.10.1, inquirer@0.8.5, html-wiring@1.2.0, download@4.4.0)

generator-angular@0.12.1 /Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.1.0, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── yosay@1.0.5 (ansi-regex@1.1.1, ansi-styles@2.1.0, word-wrap@1.1.0, strip-ansi@2.0.1, pad-component@0.0.1, minimist@1.2.0, taketalk@1.0.0, string-width@1.0.1, repeating@1.1.3)
├── wiredep@2.2.2 (propprop@0.3.0, minimist@1.2.0, lodash@2.4.2, chalk@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5, glob@4.5.3, bower-config@0.5.2)
└── yeoman-generator@0.16.0 (diff@1.0.8, dargs@0.1.0, isbinaryfile@2.0.4, debug@0.7.4, async@0.2.10, mime@1.2.11, rimraf@2.2.8, findup-sync@0.1.3, text-table@0.2.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, lodash@2.4.2, iconv-lite@0.2.11, underscore.string@2.3.3, shelljs@0.2.6, class-extend@0.1.2, chalk@0.4.0, glob@3.2.11, file-utils@0.1.5, cheerio@0.13.1, request@2.30.0, inquirer@0.4.1, download@0.1.19)
```

Comment: forget they are there then. If you don't call on them in command line they won't affect anything. Just start a new project using the one you want

Comment: The problem is the one I want doesn't show up even though it says it has installed?

Comment: installing the generator isn't the same as using the generator by calling `yo generatorName`. Do you see the one you want with the command `yo`?

Comment: 1. npm install -g generator-generatorName
2. yo generatorName

Oh okay, but this is what normally works for me, so are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: The install is global not project directory specific. You don't need to install every time you use it

Comment: I understand that. what I'm trying to say is that once I've installed it globally (only once) when I try and run it, it doesn't exist even though the global install worked? I appreciate your help btw!

Comment: Do all of the generators you've installed actually exist in `Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules/`? Basically I'm asking are yo, generator-angular-fullstack, etc. all in the same folder? (I would assume so using npm, but you never know...)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to install globally yeoman and these required tools:
npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp

Comment: I have already globally installed all of the following tools above.

Comment: you can remove all the modules installed globally, and reinstall

Comment: all your global modules are in the directory: /Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules/